# What does this line mean?, can we assign something to an object other than attribute?

Tags: c++, class, oop, wrapper

Greetings this is my first question here.

I'm really new to C++, and to Object Oriented Programming as well.

So, my tasks currently need to wrap this C++ library, the code is:

```
#include "cavc/polylineoffset.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;
    // input polyline
    cavc::Polyline<double> input;
    // add vertexes as (x, y, bulge)
    input.addVertex(0, 25, 1);
    input.addVertex(0, 0, 0);
    input.addVertex(2, 0, 1);
    input.addVertex(10, 0, -0.5);
    input.addVertex(8, 9, 0.374794619217547);
    input.addVertex(21, 0, 0);
    input.addVertex(23, 0, 1);
    input.addVertex(32, 0, -0.5);
    input.addVertex(28, 0, 0.5);
    input.addVertex(39, 21, 0);
    input.addVertex(28, 12, 0);
    input.isClosed() = true;

    // below this is the line that i dont understand
    std::vector<cavc::Polyline<double>> results = cavc::parallelOffset(input, 3.0);
}
```

So, what I don't understand is the last line. The basic C++ OOP that I understand is that we can create an object and can assign an attribute to it:

```
class MyClass {       // The class
    public:             // Access specifier
    int myNum;        // Attribute (int variable)
    string myString;  // Attribute (string variable)
};

myClass myObject;
myObject.myNum = 1;
myObject.myString = "something";
```

But, what I don't understand in the last line (from the library) is it's creating an object from a class which is `results` but after that, directly assign to something:

```
results = cavc::parallelOffset(input, 3.0);
```

This is the header file:

https://github.com/jbuckmccready/CavalierContours/blob/master/include/cavc/polylineoffset.hpp

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If the line instead said `int results = parallelOffset(input, 3.0);`, would you understand that? It's the same thing - `std::vector<cavc::Polyline<double>>` is a **typename** just like `int` is, and `cavc::` is just a **namespace** where the function is located. This doesn't really have anything to do with classes or OOP.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you Karl, for the explanation. sorry about that, its probably about my understanding that basically everything has to do with classes and OOP in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line in question is calling a function named `parallelOffset`, that was declared in a namespace called `cavc`.  The function returns an object of type `std::vector<cavc::Polyline<double>>`, so the line is declaring an object of that type and setting it equal to the value retuned by the function.

The syntax is the same as e.g.

```
float x = sin(3.0);
```

... just with a more complicated return-type (`std::vector<cavc::Polyline<double>>`, a.k.a a vector of `cavc::Polyline<double>` objects)

```
std::vector<cavc::Polyline<double>> results = cavc::parallelOffset(input, 3.0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It is very clear.